# Please Help! My LEGO BB-8 Minifig Head Is Stuck In a Helmet!

Tags: minifigures, star-wars, disassembly

[image]

My younger brother lodged his BB-8 head in a helmet, and I just can’t dislodge it.

Answer (score 4):

Show your little brother just how super chill you are by easily solving all his problems.

[image]

Just get a normal minifig and pop the head off that.  Stick the neck into BB-8 and helmet, and with the extra leverage, you'll be able to *snigg-wiggle* and separate head from helmet.

[image]

Watch the non-delicate surgical procedure [*here*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lv4PIbybYE) on *Youtube*. Just skip forward to the 52 second mark of video.  Later!